# Unable to connect oracle Database running in docker container

Tags: oracle, docker

I pulled oracle DB image and started docker container using docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:latest command.

I started the docker container, went inside the container and opened sql plus and executed the below command and created a new user.

```
CREATE USER c##test IDENTIFIED BY admin;
GRANT CONNECT TO c##test;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO c##test;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO c##test;
```

I checked the connection in sql developer running on another machine using the created user, and it said connection success.

But an application is running on the same machine where sql developer is running and it says that it is not possible to connect. I have checked the connection string, user ID and password all are correct, but I don't know why it doesn't connect.

I got below error in application side.

**testing Database connection ...java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12541: Cannot connect. No listener at host 191.168.1.8 port 1521. (CONNECTION_ID=29wHZEPHSF6VUoD7R+VIUw==)**

Comment: You said you checked the connection string, but are you sure SQL Developer is actually connecting to 191.168.1.8 port 1521?

Comment: Yes i checked, It is success

Comment: How can i send the picture?....can i send the dropbox link?

Comment: You don't need a picture, just check the `Hostname` and `Port` settings for your SQL Developer connection properties (if it's a basic connection, or the custom JDBC URL, or data for whatever other connection type you're using). If you're only getting that error from one client/app on the same machine, as you said, then the connection details must be different.